# Creating RTF file in Coldfusion -- IE shows cached version

Tags: internet-explorer, caching, coldfusion, rtf

I'm creating an RTF file in Coldfusion and writing it to the server.  Once written, I use  to display the file.  IE will load the file correctly the first time, but it loads the cached version instead of the new when the file is updated.

The file is updating on the server correctly, but I can't get IE to look at the new version.

Comment: What caching headers are you sending?

Comment: I have "no-cache" in a header in the .cfm file, but it doesn't appear to force IE to reload the RTF file that's being created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution would be to update the link with a version number on update.  So, the first time you write the file, you point to file.rtf?1.  When you update the file, update the link to file.rtf?2

If you aren't keeping track of version numbers, you could use a random integer similarly.

No, it's not elegant.  It does, however, work.

Comment: I'm currently tacking a time on the end, and that seems to be doing the trick.  Thanks!

Comment: The interface to do so is not all that obvious when you have no experience with the site.  I tried to mark it up, and wasn't allowed since I didn't have enough reputation.  I didn't even notice the check mark.